# Send E-Mails in R

Tags: r

I am trying to send E-Mails in R via Outlook and system() -call. 
I came up with something like this:

```
system(paste('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/outlook.exe"', '/c ipm.note /m test.account@mail.com&cc=test.account2@mail.com&subject=Test%20Mail&body=Test&20Body /a C:/Program Files (x86)/Test.pdf'),wait= FALSE)
```

This works fine, however I want to replace the "to", "cc" and attachement with a variable to loop through the whole thing. Something like:

```
x <- list("test.account@mail.com","test.account2@mail.com","test.account3@mail.com")

for (i in length(x)) {
system(paste('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/outlook.exe"', '/c ipm.note /m x[[i]]'),wait= FALSE)
}
```

Unfortunately, "x" is not being recognized as a variable but as a character. Is there a way to fix that? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: One alternative to a system call would be http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c("test.account@mail.com","test.account2@mail.com","test.account3@mail.com")

foreach(i=x) %do% {
   cmd <- paste0("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/outlook.exe ", "/c ipm.note /m ", i)
system(cmd, wait= FALSE)
}
```